# Solr cloud with external zookeeper

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper

I am following this tutorial:https://gist.github.com/kalharbi/fd29661b9926eb087c45

configuring solr cloud with 2 nodes.

1.Configured zookeeper on both machine:192.168.1.56:2181(localadmin4), 192.168.1.55:2182(localadmin8)
when checked status, both are working:

`localadmin8@localadmin8:/opt/solr$ ../zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh status /data/zookeeper/z2/zoo.cfg 
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /data/zookeeper/z2/zoo.cfg
Mode: leader`

```
localadmin4@localadmin4:/opt/solr$ ../zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh status /data/zookeeper/z1/zoo.cfg 
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /data/zookeeper/z1/zoo.cfg
Mode: follower
```

2.started solr

```
localadmin4@localadmin4:/opt/solr$ ./bin/solr start -c -p 8983 -z 192.168.1.56:2181,192.168.1.55:2182

localadmin8@localadmin8:/opt/solr$ ./bin/solr start -c -p 8984 -z 192.168.1.56:2181,192.168.1.55:2182
```

3.checked solr admin in browser:http://192.168.1.56:8983, http://192.168.1.55:8984 . Both the solr are working fine.

4.uploaded configuration to zookeeper:
localadmin4@localadmin4:/opt/solr$ ./server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -zkhost 192.168.1.56:2181 -confdir ./server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs/conf/ -confname l-config

5.While creating collection:
http://192.168.1.56:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=onix&numShards=2&replicationFactor=1&collection.configName=l-config

it gives me following response:

```xml
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">33011</int>
</lst>
<lst name="failure">
<str name="127.0.1.1:8984_solr">org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:Server refused connection at: http://127.0.1.1:8984/solr</str>
</lst>
<lst name="success">
<lst name="127.0.1.1:8983_solr">
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1957</int>
</lst>
<str name="core">onix_shard2_replica1</str>
</lst>
</lst>
</response>
```

instead of hitting on 192.168.1.55:8984_solr , it is hitting 127.0.1.1:8984_solr.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by Solr detecting its own, wrong IP on startup, and thus, using the wrong IP when registering the node in the Solr cluster.

You can [tell Solr which IP to use by giving the embedded Jetty container the IP to use](http://shal.in/post/127561227271/how-to-make-apache-solr-listen-on-a-specific-ip) (or for only intra-node communication, using `SOLR_HOST` should be enough).

> Someone asked me how to ensure that Solr is exposed exclusively on a server’s internal IP address so I thought this bit of information would be useful more generally.
>   On Linux, edit the solr.in.sh file, find the property called SOLR_HOST (it is commented out by default) and set its value to the IP address or the host name that you want Solr to listen for requests.
>
> `SOLR_HOST="192.168.1.55"`
>
> The procedure is similar on Windows, except that the file to be edited is solr.in.cmd.
>
> It was pointed out to me later that setting SOLR_HOST is not enough because the host/IP set by that property is only used by SolrCloud for making inter-shard requests. We also need to set a property used by Jetty in solr.in.sh or solr.in.cmd:
>
> `SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Djetty.host=192.168.1.55"`

Answer (score -2):

Did you add IP like this 127.0.1.1 may it should be `127.0.0.1` crosscheck.

Also make sure you modified zoo.cfg file correctly with proper server nodes and server id mapping files.

ex:

```
 server.1=127.0.0.1:2222:2223
 server.2=127.0.0.1:3333:3334
```

My blog on [External Zookeeper with Solr Cloud](http://vinodtechstuff.blogspot.in/2017/08/solr-in-production.html)  might help you.